# Convert JSON into a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How do I convert the following JSON type into a javascript array?

```js
[
  {
    "Product Name":"CPE 10281",
    "Application":"Tyres",
    "Weight":150,
    "Cost to Produce":5000,
    "Grade":"A",
    "Cost to Sell":40000,
    "Strength":100
  },
  {
    "Product Name":"CPE 10282",
    "Application":"computers",
    "Weight":250,
    "Cost to Produce":4000,
    "Grade":"H",
    "Cost to Sell":25000,
    "Strength":90
  },
  {
    "Product Name":"CPE 10283",
    "Application":"paint",
    "Weight":150,
    "Cost to Produce":5000,
    "Grade":"A",
    "Cost to Sell":15000,
    "Strength":90
  }
]
```

What would be the call procedure for any of a given entry in relation to a product name?

Thank you everyone for your comments and solution. What I have till now is

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "dataProductJSON.json",
    dataType: 'json',
    mimeType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        
        $.each(data, function (key, val){

            $.each(val, function (innerKey, innerValue){
                
                item.push('<li id="' + innerKey + '">' + innerKey +" : " + innerValue + '</li>');
            });
        });
        alert (item[2]);
        $('<ul/>', {
            'class': 'interest-list',
            html: item.join('')
        }).appendTo('body');
    },

});
```

My query was after reading the data from a JSON file how do I convert it into a javascript array.

Comment: Thats a javascript array.

Comment: `JSON.parse` the text? You haven't even mentioned how you are obtaining that content.

Comment: "What would be the call procedure for any of a given entry in relation to a product name?" — That sounds like a different question to deal with after you've parsed it.

Comment: actually this is an `array`

Answer (score 4):

Modern browsers support [`JSON.parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466(v=vs.85).aspx), as it's defined in `ECMA-262 5th Edition`.

Its usage is like the following:

```
var json = '{"response":true,"number":1}',
    obj = JSON.parse(obj);

alert(obj.count);
```

For the browsers that don't, you can implement it using [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

**ADDITIONAL NOTES:**

If you're already using **jQuery**, there is a `$.parseJSON` function that maps to `JSON.parse` if available or a form of `eval` in older browsers. However, this performs additional, unnecessary checks that are also performed by `JSON.parse`.

In conclusion, for the best **performance**, I'd recommend using it like:

```
var json = '{"response":true,"number":1}',
    obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
```

This will ensure you use native `JSON.parse` immediately, rather than having jQuery perform sanity checks on the string before passing it to the native parsing function.

**HOW TO USE:**

As you are making an ajax call, you just need to parse the data on `success`, like so:

```
success: function (data) {
    data = JSON && JSON.parse(data) || $.parseJSON(data);
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but want to point out one minor issue. JSON && JSON.parse(data) will throw an error in IE<8.  As a workaround, use (window.JSON && window.JSON.parse(data)) to test for the JSON object.  That avoids the error and it defaults to the jQuery method as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you have above is a JavaScript array. If the JSON is in string form then you will need to convert it using `JSON.parse(string);`

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, this is already an object, if it's a string you can make it an object by using

`var obj = JSON.parse(string)`

and then you can use it like this:

`obj[0]["Product Name"]` <- Will get the value of "Product Name" of the first record.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is a string you can use:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
```

Example:

```
var text = '[
  {
    "Product Name":"CPE 10281",
    "Application":"Tyres",
    "Weight":150,
    "Cost to Produce":5000,
    "Grade":"A",
    "Cost to Sell":40000,
    "Strength":100
  },
  {
    "Product Name":"CPE 10282",
    "Application":"computers",
    "Weight":250,
    "Cost to Produce":4000,
    "Grade":"H",
    "Cost to Sell":25000,
    "Strength":90
  },
  {
    "Product Name":"CPE 10283",
    "Application":"paint",
    "Weight":150,
    "Cost to Produce":5000,
    "Grade":"A",
    "Cost to Sell":15000,
    "Strength":90
  }
]'
var array= JSON.parse(text);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will read that.

Comment: Sorry. Here is the complete comment again (with working link):  ///  Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks again. I edited the answer, hope is useful now.